# Get Nested ListView by name in Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have the following nested ListViews:

```
<!-- Display a list of each CustomTab -->
<!-- Drag & Drop functionality implemented in code behind using ListViewDragDropManager -->
<ListView Name="TasksListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Model.TaskCollection, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          BorderThickness="0">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            .....
            <!-- Parameters List -->
            <ListView Name="TaskParameterListView"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding TaskParameterCollection, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      BorderThickness="0">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        .....
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>            
</ListView>
```

I need to get access to the `TaskParameterListView` in code behind.  How can I get a reference to this object?

With the `TasksListView` I can access it simply by calling `this.TasksListView`

Comment: What do you need to do in code behind that cannot be achieved in XAML or via binding?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can find inner ListView using FrameworkTemplate.FindName:

```
DependencyObject container = TasksListView
   .ItemContainerGenerator
   .ContainerFromItem(TasksListView.SelectedItem);

if (container != null)
{
   ContentPresenter presenter = GetPresenter(container);
   ListView listView = presenter
      .ContentTemplate
      .FindName("TaskParameterListView", presenter) as ListView;
}
```

Additional method to find a ContentPresenter inside the ListBoxItem:

```
private static ContentPresenter GetPresenter(DependencyObject reference)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(reference); i++)
   {
      DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(reference, i);
      ContentPresenter presenter =
         child as ContentPresenter ??
         GetPresenter(child);

      if (presenter != null)
      { return presenter; }
   }

   return null;
}
```